# Adding javascript to module and access drupalSettings without jQuery

Tags: 8, javascript

I am trying to create a Drupal 8 version of the [Mautic Drupal module](https://github.com/pusle/mautic-drupal). Currently I have just ported the Drupal 7 version as is, and the script for Mautic forms along with the tracking pixel is printed in a block. Mautic now uses a tracking script and I want to update the module to use it. The tracking script looks like this (notice the Mautic base url required):

### js/mautic_drupal_tracking_code.js

```
(function(w,d,t,u,n,a,m){w['MauticTrackingObject']=n;
    w[n]=w[n]||function(){(w[n].q=w[n].q||[]).push(arguments)},a=d.createElement(t),
        m=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];a.async=1;a.src=u;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script', + drupalSettings.mautic_drupal.mautic_drupal_tracking_code.base_url + '/mtc.js','mt');

mt('send', 'pageview');
```

The script is showing on the page, but as I am trying to avoid jQuery, I can not find out how to access the `drupalSettings` variable.

My module code is updated and not in sync with the github repo. Here are a description of the files:

### mautic_drupal.libraries.yml

```
mautic_drupal_tracking_code:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    js/mautic_drupal_tracking_code.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/drupalSettings
```

### mautic_drupal.module

```
/**
 * Implements hook_page_attachments_alter().
 *
 * @param array $page
 */
function mautic_drupal_page_attachments_alter(array &$page) {
  $config = \Drupal::service('config.factory')->get('mautic_drupal.settings');
  $mautic_url = trim($config->get('base_url'), ' \t\n\r\0\x0B/');

  if ($mautic_url != '') {
    $page['#attached']['drupalSettings']['mautic_drupal']['mautic_drupal_tracking_code']['base_url'] = $mautic_url;
    $page['#attached']['library'][] = 'mautic_drupal/mautic_drupal_tracking_code';
  }
}
```

On the site, the script is showing, and the base url setting is set. But alas, I can not access the settings in my javascript, I can only find examples of how to do that in jQuery scripts.

Is this possible to do in pure javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set a weight on the js file:

```
  js:
    js/mautic_drupal_tracking_code.js: { weight: -18 }
```

There is a core issue, that the dependencies don't get the correct priority. The weight is a workaround for this:

[Replace custom weights with dependencies in library declarations](https://www.drupal.org/node/1945262)

If you can't get `drupalSettingsLoader.js` running in the correct order, you can for testing purpose put the code to load the json array at the top of your custom js:

```
(function () {

  'use strict';

  var settingsElement = document.querySelector('head > script[type="application/json"][data-drupal-selector="drupal-settings-json"], body > script[type="application/json"][data-drupal-selector="drupal-settings-json"]');

  window.drupalSettings = {};

  if (settingsElement !== null) {
    window.drupalSettings = JSON.parse(settingsElement.textContent);
  }
})();
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. Thanks for the tip thought, I did not know of this issue.

Comment: it should work without jquery, see the edited answer.